# Server does not receive JSON object while using volley on android

Tags: php, android, json, android-volley

I tried to use volley to send JSON object to server and get a response but it seems the server doesnt get the data.

If i tried to just echo back it works, but if i try to read the JSON object on server and react, i get error on volley. I also try to echo back the JSON object and still get error.
When i use HttpRequest everything works ok.
I added the same Headers as in HttpRequest and Volley, Maybe is connected to UTF8? which i do on setEntity

i get the data on PHP like this:

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
```

My volley code:

```
JsonObjectRequest req = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,
           URL, jsonObject ,
           new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
               @Override
               public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                       Log.d(TAG,"Response: " + response.toString());

               }
           }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
               @Override
               public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                   VolleyLog.e("Error: ", error.getMessage());
               }
           })
            {     
                @Override
                public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError { 
                        Map<String, String>  params = new HashMap<String, String>();  
                        params.put("Accept", "application/json");  
                        params.put("Content-Type", "application/json");

                        return params;  
                }
            };
    ;
```

Anyone have an idea?

Comment: Out of interest what happens you have the treturn type as just Object.class? Also, what's the volley error? And finally : use error.printStackTrace() instead

Comment: I am facing the same problem . did u get any solution ?

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that my volley code was ok. the problem was on the server side.

Using Breadbin comment and replacing the VolleyLog.e with error.printStackTrace() helped to find the problem.